# How can I read a myGo.exe standard out from c++?

Tags: go, pipe, stdout

I have a Process class in C++20. This works beautifully for executables made in c++, However if I try to open a Go executable, I cannot read from it's standard out or error, nor write to it's standard in.

in c++ I have the following tester:

```cpp
// MultiTester.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Process.h"

int main()
{
    Process hello(1, "HelloWorld.exe"); hello.start();
    Process foo(2, "HelloFoo.exe"); foo.start();
    Process bar(3, "HelloBar.exe"); bar.start();

    std::string helloResponse = hello.readPipe(Process::OUTPUT);
    std::string fooResponse = foo.readPipe(Process::OUTPUT);
    std::string barResponse = bar.readPipe(Process::ERR);
    //Process::enum TYPE { INPUT, OUTPUT, ERR }; could also do i.e. bar.ERR
    //func getHandle(TYPE type) is included as public yet used mostly internally

    std::cout << helloResponse << std::endl;
    std::cout << fooResponse << std::endl;
    std::cout << barResponse << std::endl;

    //pause execution
    std::cout << "Press character and Enter to end" << std::endl;
    std::string enter; std::cin >> enter;

    //close everyone
    hello.writePipe(enter); 
    foo.writePipe(enter); 
    bar.writePipe(enter); 

    exit(0);
}
```

Now if the executables are written in c++, the tester reads "Hello World", Hello Foo", and "Hello Bar" respectively. HelloBar.exe in this example prints "Hello Bar" to std::cerr, and all three in C++ end with a cin::get();

However if the same executables are written in Go, I get nothing. I have tried several printing methods. Combining the print lines from my 3 Go executables to save space, here is the Go code:

```
package main
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello world")
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout,"hello foo")
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr,"hello bar")
    
    in := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    in.Scan()
}
```

For reference, my process class is heavily based on [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)

@Mooing Duck: The Processes can stay running, I have a made for testing a ConsoleCalculator.exe that takes a float, a character, and a float. If you enter, say, "2+2", it gives the answer "4" and asks for a 'y' for more or anything else to quit. I made a calcTester.exe to open it with my Process class, and I can continue entering calculations through the tester proxy. That is, my c++ ConsoleCalculator works with the tester, not my Go ConsoleCalculator.

P.S. my Process class can be found in [this project](https://github.com/Akadine/new-cg-brutaltester).

Comment: In the `go` binary, did you type something into stdin to verify that the processes finished?

Comment: After reading the message from the child my tester waits for a keypress, stores the value, and then sends it to the child to terminate the child. The child should stay running until communications has ended and gets a signal to quit from the parent. I am remaking https://github.com/dreignier/cg-brutaltester in c++, I am trying to run https://github.com/robostac/coders-strike-back-referee made for the Brutal Tester and known to work, with a couple of player files. As stated this works for C++written executables, I am having trouble with Go executables.

Comment: Specifically, I'm guessing that the go binary buffered the output internally, and didn't flush it to stdout yet.  C++ binaries will automatically flush buffers to stdout before it tries to read from stdin, but I don't know if go does as well

Comment: There is a comment in the read me for the original Brutal Tester saying that you had to alter your player files to flush, but the referees all worked "out-of-the" box and compiled. I have tested this with c,  c++, and java referees all with success. If I can get the GO to work, I'll GitHub the thing. Can I do something on the tester side to fix the flush thing?

Comment: Also, after writing to the child, Sleep(1) or 1 millisecond is needed in c and c++, and 3-5 milliseconds for java before trying to read from the child. The referee waits 100 milliseconds to give the player some time to calculate, and the player loses if they have not printed to stdout by then. I've tried 2000 or 2 seconds for the GO binaries with no joy.

Comment: https://github.com/Akadine/new-cg-brutaltester